# Question about refining finite cover of a compact k in a TVS E by translates of neighboroods of 0

Tags: functional-analysis

In a TVS E with countable basis (U_n) of open neighborood of 0 , if K is a compact K of E, it is always possible to find fot each integer n a finite set T_n such that K is covered by the open sets t + U_n where t is an element of T_n.

I am asking , with the supplementary conditions that the U_n are balanced and decreasing for inclusion and such that, for each integer n, U_(n+1) + U_(n+1) is contained in U_n,

if we can impose for each integer n, T_(n+1) is contained in the set  T_n + U_(n+1) (the sum of the sets T_n and U_n). This is not evident for me, so I need a prooof of this fact if there is one because I found this implicitely affirmed in a proof of the following lemma:

let f : E -> F linear continuous and surjective (E and F TVS being metrisable and complete) and K a compact subset of F, then there is a compact subset L of E such that f(L) = K

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple : for each n, the compact K is covered by a finite number of open sets of the form t+ U_(n+1) where t belongs to the finite set T_n . Then it is obvious that we have, for each n, T_(n+1) contained in T_n + U_(n+1).